# SQL Server Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, switch-statement

I am trying to run this sql statement, but it generate error "Incorrect syntax near update"

```
Select Case @location 

        When 'MediaFiles' Then update tblMediaFiles set mdActive=1
        When 'MediaFiles1' Then update tblMediaFiles1 set mdActive=1
        When 'MediaFiles2' Then update tblMediaFiles2 set mdActive=2
        Else update tblMediaFiles4 set mdActive=1

    End
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL has a [CASE *expression*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) that goes where, er, expressions would go

Use the [IF *statement*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) instead

```
IF @location = 'MediaFiles' 
    update tblMediaFiles set mdActive=1
ELSE IF @location = 'MediaFiles1' 
    update tblMediaFiles1 set mdActive=1
ELSE IF @location = 'MediaFiles2' 
    update tblMediaFiles2 set mdActive=2
ELSE
    update tblMediaFiles4 set mdActive=1
```

Answer (score 6):

From MSDN:

> The CASE expression cannot be used to control the flow of execution of
>   Transact-SQL statements, statement blocks, user-defined functions, and
>   stored procedures. For a list of control-of-flow methods, see
>   [Control-of-Flow Language (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174290.aspx).

You really want to use an `IF-ELSE` structure for this kind of logic.